# Syntax for If statements in Python

Tags: python

What syntax is wrong in this code. My logic behind it is if there is no 'noemail' in filetype field and ''(blank) in email field and 'dm' in effort type field then i want certain o/p else I want iterate with no 'noemail' in filetype field and ''(blank) in email field and 'tm' in effort type field.Please help me with the syntax.

```
 import csv
 csv.register_dialect('piper', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
 with open('temp3.txt','rb') as csvfile:
 for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='piper'):
    print row['FILENAME'] ##gives output like Jun14WSJ_CNYR_EMAIL_CAP_DM1_20140818.txt           or Apr14WSJ_CNYR_NOEMAIL_CAP_TM_20140728.txt
    print row['EMAIL'] ##gives output like swansev@charter.net or blank
    print row['EFFORT_TYPE'] gives TM or DM
    abc = str(row['FILENAME'])
    xyz = str(row['EMAIL'])
    sdf = str(row['EFFORT_TYPE'])
    if 'NOEMAIL' in abc:
        if '' in xyz:
            if 'DM' in sdf:
                print(row['PREFIX']+row['PRINT_PUB_CD'])
            elif 'TM' in sdf:
                print('Its DM.')
```

i/p
SEQ_NUM|ICS_ORIG_STRT_DT|EDW_FIRST_OUT_IFP_DT|CURR_DT|DEV_GE_NUM_DAYS|DEV_LE_NUM_DAYS|FILENAME|CAMPAIGN_NAME_DESC|CAMPAIGN_WAVE|MARKET_SEGMENT|CAMPAIGN_NAME|CAMPAIGN_WAVE_RUN|EFFORT_TYPE|EFFORT_NUM|UU_ID|PRINT_ACCT_NUM|PRINT_PUB_CD|PREFIX|SUFFIX|FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|EMAIL|PHONE_NUM|BUS_PHONE|CO_NAME|STREET_NUM|ADDR|ADDR2|CITY|STATE_PROVINCE|ZIP_POSTAL|ZIP4|TRACK_CD|VANITY_URL|BILL_FORM|LETTER_TEXT|OUTER
119|20140602|00010101|20140818|0|21|Jun14WSJ_CNYR_EMAIL_CAP_DM1_20140818.txt|Jun14WSJ_CNYR_EMAIL_CAP_DM1|WSJ_CNYR_EMAIL_CAP_DM1|CNYR|WSJ_CNYR_EMAIL_CAP|Jun14|DM|1|rnirenberg2|030409237002|J|||RONALD|NIRENBERG|zt60@aol.com|9733554718|9733554718||711|NEWARK###AVE||KENILWORTH|NJ|07033|1744|aaqitn56|wsj.com/activate7|JB217|JFI18|JO310

Comment: The [strack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) will tell you.

Comment: Not sure if this needs to be said, but `if '' in xyz` is not the same thing as "if xyz is empty". If that's what you want, you can do `if len(xyz) == 0` or just `if not xyz`

Comment: @Kevin That helps.Again i am not getting the print 'its dm'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong here:

```
if 'DM' in sdf:
    print(row['PREFIX']+row['PRINT_PUB_CD'])
    elif 'TM' in sdf:
        print('Its DM.')
```

There is no `if` block at the same level as your `elif` block, so `elif` is not valid.  De-indent the block to match it up with whichever `if` block it should apply to:

```
if 'DM' in sdf:
    print(row['PREFIX']+row['PRINT_PUB_CD'])
elif 'TM' in sdf:
    print('Its DM.')
```

Or change it to an `if` block.  It's not immediately clear what the correct solution is, but at least we know what the problem is.

Comment: I added my requirement please check it

Comment: I think I fixed it.my script us running but I am not getting any data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `elif` does not match in indentation with any `if` statement. In your case, you will have to un-indent the `elif` and the following `print` statement by one level each to get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The last `elif` needs to be an `if` if you want to nest the statements

```
 if 'TM' in sdf:
    print('Its DM.')
```

Or dedent if you do not want to nest:

```
if 'DM' in sdf:
       print(row['PREFIX']+row['PRINT_PUB_CD'])
elif 'TM' in sdf:
      print('Its DM.')
```

`elif's` must be at the same level as  your `if` statements

```
for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='piper'):
    print row['FILENAME'] ##gives output like Jun14WSJ_CNYR_EMAIL_CAP_DM1_20140818.txt           or Apr14WSJ_CNYR_NOEMAIL_CAP_TM_20140728.txt
    print row['EMAIL'] ##gives output like swansev@charter.net or blank
    print row['EFFORT_TYPE'] #gives TM or DM
    abc = row['FILENAME']
    xyz = row['EMAIL']
    sdf = row['EFFORT_TYPE']
    if 'NOEMAIL' in abc and not xyz and 'DM' in sdf:
            print(row['PREFIX']+row['PRINT_PUB_CD'])
    elif 'NOEMAIL' in abc and 'TM'  in sdf and not xyz:
        print('Its DM.')
```

It seems you were thinking the `elif` would take into account the previous statements but you need to use two blocks, each with all the conditions.

If you wanted the first two  conditions and either `'DM' in sdf or 'TM'  in sdf`
 you could use `or`

```
if 'NOEMAIL' in abc and not in xyz and 'DM' in sdf or 'TM'  in sdf:
```

Comment: please explain.still not getting the o/p as it dm

Comment: it depends what you are trying to do, do you want nested if statements or what exactlty if the flow supposed to be?

Comment: my logic behind it is if there is no 'noemail' in filetype field and ''(blank) in email field and 'dm' in effort type field then i want certain o/p else I want iterate with no 'noemail' in filetype field and ''(blank) in email field and 'tm' in effort type field.

Comment: @Rajarshi, I edited based on your comment but i am not 100 percent sure if I understand

Comment: ,I have used it.Still it is not showing the result.Do u have any idea why it is not showing it is not dm

Comment: are they the conditions you want to check?

Comment: ,I have used it.Still it is not showing the result.Do u have any idea why it is not showing it is not dm.again I changed the '' in xyz to len(xyz) == 0.            if 'NOEMAIL' in abc and len(xyz) == 0 and 'DM' in sdf:
            print(row['PREFIX']+row['PRINT_PUB_CD'])
        elif 'NOEMAIL' in abc and 'TM'  in sdf and '' in xyz:
            print('Its DM.')

Comment: without knowing the input it is hard to say